# Is there an API to programmatically set e-mail templates and Action Links in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I use automation tools, such as Terraform and Ansible, to deploy infrastructures and applications.

Do you know of any way to **programmatically** set up the e-mail templates and the Action Links in **Firebase**? It seems that this can only be done in the console, at this time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (and can determine from looking at the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/patch)) there is currently no API to update the email templates or action links that Firebase Authentication uses.

It might be useful to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.